# problema ao logar em formulário com php

Tags: php, javascript, html

desenvolvi um sistema de login em php nesse [site](http://fabiorabin.com.br/login) sem banco de dados com uma senha fixa `localhost` tudo funciona normalmente mais quando upei os arquivos para o servidor e tento acessar ele chega a carregar a página porem retorna para o inicio e na `url` do navegador aparece que não é seguro tem como consertar isso segue as imagens e o código fonte.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
na imagem acima aparece ao lado da `URL` não é seguro e isso não me deixa logar na pagina `main.php` lembrando que `localhost` funciona normalmente

Login:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" name="login" id="login" class="login form-login" onsubmit="return validaCampo(); return false;">
                <div class="box-form-login">
                    <div class="text-left">
                        <h4 class="title">Painel do cliente</h4>
                        <p class="text">Para ter acesso a todo o conteúdo do Fábio Rabin basta acessar o painel com o
                            usuário e senha enviados para o seu email.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="user" id="user" class="form-control user" placeholder="Digite seu nome" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control user" placeholder="Digite sua senha" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-primary send">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
?>
<?php
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
include("bd.php");
if ($valida[$user] == $pass) {
    setcookie("logado", "1");
    echo "<script>location.href='main.php'</script>";
} else {
   /* echo "Usuário ou senha incorretos!";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href=login>";
    echo "Clique aqui</a> para tentar novamente.";
    echo "</a></font>";*/
}
?>

<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="bg-color hidden-xs hidden-sm">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center pull-right">
            <p class="title">Poxa vida!<br> Seu usuário ou senha estão incorretos!<br/> <span><a href="login">- Clique aqui e tente novamente -</a></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.php:

```
    <?php
if (IsSet($_COOKIE["logado"])) {
} else {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=login">';
    exit;

}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <a href="logout.php" class="link-logout">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <!--<img src="img/img-download.png" class="img-responsive img-download hidden-xs hidden-sm"
             alt="Faça o download dos conteúdos"/>-->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
            <div class="box-download">
                <p class="text"><span>E ai cara seja bem-vindo!</span><br/>Aqui você vai encontrar todo o conteúdo necessário sobre o Fábio Rabin, basta
                    clicar no botão abaixo e efetuar o download.</p>
                <a href="conteudo.zip" class="content-download">Baixar conteúdo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

logout.php:

```
<?php
setcookie("logado", "");
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function deleteCookie(nome) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setTime(exdate.getTime() + (-1 * 24 * 3600
                * 5000));
            document.cookie = nome + "=" + escape("") + ((-1
                == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <p class="text"><span>Você desconectou!</span><br>
                Aguarde, você será redirecionado <br>para página inicial.</p>

            <p>Se demorar muito <a href="login">clique aqui</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
    deleteCookie("logado");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

bd.php(aqui é aonde eu coloco usuário e a senha fixa)

```
<?php
$valida[fabiorabin] = "download123";
?>
```

Comment: Perece como "não seguro" porque não tem HTTPS/TLS, isto é o que o Chrome analisa apenas, qualquer página de login sem HTTPS é inseguro, pela lógica do Chrome. *Mas, ironicamente o sistema também está bem inseguro, desde comparações com `==`, utilizando apenas um cookie para validar (qualquer um pode dar um `document.cookie = "logado=1";`) e armazenamento de senhas em texto plano.*

Answer (score 2):

O "Não seguro" significa que o seu site não tem protocolo de segurança [SSL](https://www.tecmundo.com.br/seguranca/1896-o-que-e-ssl-.htm). Você pode conseguir esse protocolo em alguns sites de hospedagem pagos e gratuitos, como foi sugerido pelo @Inkeliz. Mas não é por isso que você não consegue se logar. O que acontece é que você está liberando o ambiente (**main.php**) através de cookies. E se no seu navegador estiver desabilidada essa permissão, você não consegue inseri-lo, para fazer a verificação posterior.

Eu consegui me logar tranquilamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha sugestão. Trabalhe com `$_SESSION` do **php** que você não terá esse problema.

Comment: Nota: é possível ter de graça utilizando [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Inclusive utilizando o [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/), ao invés de NGinx/Apache, ele já utiliza o Let's Encrypt.

Comment: @Inkeliz, boa. Vou editar.

Answer (score 2):

O Google anunciou em seu blog com o seguinte artigo “Movendo-se para uma Web mais Segura“, no qual explicou que em Janeiro 2017 houve uma atualização no Google Chrome 56, que marca páginas HTTP que coletam senhas ou cartões de crédito como NÃO SEGURO na barra de url e com cadeado de segurança vermelho.

Até então, apenas as páginas em HTTP que solicitam informações como senhas e cartões de crédito apareciam como páginas não segura. Porém, o plano do Google Chrome é a longo prazo, que pretende marcar todos os sites HTTP como não seguro ou não protegidos.

Veja o que a Google tem a dizer sobre o assunto:  [HTTPS nos principais sites](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/https/grid/?hl=pt-BR)

**Para desenvolvedores e webmasters:**

Há um site de teste que possui duas páginas, uma HTTP  http://www.httpvshttps.com/  e outra HTTPS   https://www.httpvshttps.com/ , e alternando entre elas é mostrado na sessão atual do navegador a diferença no carregamento de ambas.

Tendo em vista o acima exposto e se você não tiver um site que seja seguro e não ranqueado no mecanismo de busca do Google, corra para contratar um selo de segurança SSL e faça a instalação HTTPS em seu site. :)